# What Is @@DEF_SORTORDER_ID Used For?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I've looked through [Microsoft's SQL Server site](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Search/en-US/sqlserver?query=@@DEF_SORTORDER_ID&Refinement=30&ac=4), [Googled this](https://www.google.com/search?q=TRANSACT%20SQL%20@@DEF_SORTORDER_ID&oq=TRANSACT%20SQL%20@@DEF_SORTORDER_ID&aqs=chrome.0.69i57j69i58.4434j0&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8), and even [checked Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=@@DEF_SORTORDER_ID) for an answer (note on the last two, this will change within a day or so), and yet I'm not finding anything for the below `SELECT` query:

```
SELECT @@DEF_SORTORDER_ID
```

What/how is this used in SQL Server (2008R2; it also appears to be available in 2012 and 2005)?

Comment: Presumably short for "default sort order ID" mentioned in message [17657 here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917589.aspx). That message number now refers to default collation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the SQL sort order ID, use [`SERVERPROPERTY('SqlSortOrder')`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174396.aspx). The list of sort orders for ancient SQL 7.0 products is still available in places like [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917538.aspx). Nowadays though everybody calls it ['the server collation'](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144250%28v=sql.105%29.aspx).

That being said, I never seen `@@DEF_SORTORDER_ID` before and I don't know what it is...

Comment: It produces the same result as the SERVERPROPERTY('SqlSortOrder') on our servers; MSDN typically defines things well, so it was peculiar that it wasn't listed there.